# intent.putExtra from Activity to fragment returns null

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to get a string from 1 activity to another, and then get that string from the second activity to the Fragment inside of it. I am getting null return from the fragment. This is the code for each of the following.

Activity 1

```
findViewById<Button>(R.id.button).setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("IPValT", IPVal)
            startActivity(intent)
```

Activity 2

```
var IPVal2: String = intent.getStringExtra("IPValT").toString()
        camBut.setOnClickListener {
                val intent = Intent(this, Video::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("IPValT2", IPVal2)
                startActivity(intent)
```

Fragment

```
val ipcomm: String = mainAct.intent.getStringExtra("IPVal2").toString()
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your key value is mismachted .In your fragment add **IPValT2** instead of IPVal2

```
val ipcomm: String = mainAct.intent.getStringExtra("IPValT2").toString()
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply! I have seen and corrected the mistake, but the value still remains at null.

Comment: then print value IPVal from first activity. check its null or not?

Comment: I have printed the ipval for both first and second activity, and they show the correct string. It is just from the activity to the fragment that it seems to have a null value

Comment: can you post fragment open function

Comment: I decided to circumvent the problem by moving the button in the fragment to the main activity; The fragment was for a different purpose that was no longer needed. Thanks for helping though :)

Answer (score 0):

You can access like this

```
(activity as MainActivity).IPVal2
```